# How to measure SNR of a telephone Line? What is the device (without using router)?

Tags: snr

I'm a beginner level eng student. I've just find this place and I need your help.

**I need to create SNR detector without using a router login.** 
So,

1. Is there any small device to measure SNR by directly connecting phoneline to device? (without using router login)
2. Can I use arduino to make the snr detector?
3. If you have knoledge, please explain that what is the best and smallest way to make this.

Please help me. This is for a project!
Thank you all Engineers and other in this place.

Comment: How would you *theoretically* measure SNR?

Comment: ratio of power-signal and power-noise. But need to know practically side.

Comment: Is this a POTS line, ISDN or ADSL (xDSL)?

Comment: So, what is the signal you're interested in? You have to define what's signal and what isn't before you can measure the relative power levels.

Comment: @jippie, Yes. ADSL.. We can find SNR by Accessing into router. But, I need to know how router measure it? What are the ics that they use.. and can't we make a device to measure SNR by using Arduino etc.

Comment: I think you're better off by learning how to retrieve the data from the router. SNR measurement in an DSL router is not for the feint hearted. It requires lots of electronics and lots of math and programming. In the end you would've built your own router. Some routers can be queried over SNMP, SSH or TELNET.

Comment: @Dave Tweed,It is a telephone ADSL signal. Thanks for helping all!

Answer (score 4):

Measuring the SNR of an ADSL signal is not a simple proposition. ADSL uses hundreds of subcarriers, each carrying a 16-QAM signal, as shown in the constellation diagram shown below, courtesy Wikimedia Commons.

[image: constellation diagram]

The ADSL modem performs adaptive equalization to get the best possible constellation for each carrier, where "best possible" means that the individual points in the diagram have the least amount of "fuzziness" — the clusters of individual sample points are more tightly grouped. This accounts for the non-noise distortions of the channel (phone line), including its phase and frequency response.

The signal-to-noise ratio is derived from whatever fuzziness remains, which is due to external noise sources, crosstalk among the subcarriers and intersymbol interference. The modem does some statistical calculations that compare the actual signal sample values with their idealized values in order to come up with a number for SNR.

If the SNR on a particular subcarrier gets bad enough, the clusters will begin to overlap each other, leading to bit errors. When this happens, the modem can fall back to a simpler modulation scheme that has fewer points, or stop using that subcarrier altogether.

So the bottom line is, if you want to measure ADSL SNR, you need an ADSL modem chip. Since you already have one in your router, you might as well use it. Standalone SNR meters have modem chips inside them, too.